# Python: "'str' does not support the buffer interface" on subprocess.communicate (migrating to 3.x)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, subprocess

```
 cmd_a = "a\n{0}\nt\n{0}\nda\nw\n".format(number)
 cmd_b = subprocess.Popen("fdisk %s" % file_name, shell=True,stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
 fdisk_cmd.communicate(cmd_a)
```

This code works with Python2.x but on Python3.x it gives me:

```
 File "bootimage.py", line 44, in do_install_file
|     fdisk_cmd.communicate(cmd_a)
|   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 930, in communicate
|     self.stdin.write(input)
| TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

Comment: try `communicate(cmd_a.encode("ascii"))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In python 3, `subprocess` streams are binary.

To write a string, just encode a binary, in your case `ascii` codec is OK:

```
fdisk_cmd.communicate(cmd_a.encode("ascii"))
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked , don't see this error now. But would it anyway impact on functionality ?

Comment: what do you mean? the data is passed to process input, you cah check that yourself